# MPAndroidChart Line chart - text along with line

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I need to show certain text along with data lines drawn on a chart. Please see [this graph sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Uhk.png) for reference. I am unable to figure out a way to do this with MPAndroid Chart. At this point I am showing them as Legends at the bottom but since there are many different data series, I need to show these along with Lines. Please do let me know if there are ways to handle this.

```
LimitLine[] allpoints = new LimitLine[mChart.getLineData().getDataSetCount()];
for (int i=0; i < mChart.getLineData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {
    allpoints[i] = new LimitLine(ChartXMLDataProviderFiveToEighteenBMI.dataSets.get(i).getYMax(), String.valueOf(i));
    allpoints[i].setLineColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    allpoints[i].setLineWidth(1f);
    allpoints[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    allpoints[i].setTextSize(7f); 
 }
```

Comment: Please share some relevant pieces of code you tried so far.

Comment: I tried something like below which didn't work:  LimitLine[] allpoints = new LimitLine[mChart.getLineData().getDataSetCount()] ;
        for (int i=0; i < mChart.getLineData().getDataSetCount(); i++)
        {
            allpoints[i] = new LimitLine(ChartXMLDataProviderFiveToEighteenBMI.dataSets.get(i).getYMax(), String.valueOf(i)) ;
            allpoints[i].setLineColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            allpoints[i].setLineWidth(1f);
            allpoints[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
            allpoints[i].setTextSize(7f);

        }

Comment: Got this working for me, just had to add additional line to add the limit line above to the axis. Good for now. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question to include your code. Please answer your own question by providing the code you used to fix the problem. It might help others in the future.